The behavior missmatch before and after converting a MLX generated model to GGUF(accessed through ollama)
Edit 1:
Let me make the question more specific. The model we fine tuned is a code generation model and will give output as code completion style.(text generation style).
Sample input: system.out
Sample output: system.out.println(xxx)
After converting to Ollama recognized format and launched by Ollama, the style changed to sth like:
Sample input: system.out
Sample output: It seems you're trying to blablabla, and seems also lost some code related knowledge which fed by our fine tuning.
Original version:
We fine tuned a model using MLX and successfully saved the model, check this link for more details.
The generated model works so far so good with command like mlx_lm.generate --model new_model --prompt "tell me sth about sql"  --temp 0.01 --ignore-chat-template.
However, after converting it to gguf format and accessed through Ollama, the output just varies and not as expected.
The procedure to convert it to gguf is like:
python llama.cpp/convert_hf_to_gguf.py path/new_model --outfile path/new_model.gguf


Create modelfile with content like:
FROM ./new_model.gguf
# sets the temperature to 1 [higher is more creative, lower is more coherent]
PARAMETER temperature 0.01

Use Ollama to create the final artifact:
ollama create new_model -f modelfile

Launch ollama with ollama run new_model and evaluate it.
